# Is there punishment for leaving Islam then rejoining?

Tags: punishment, kufr, belief

In one of my previous questions I asked for evidence for Islam being true: [The evidence for Islam being true](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/60568/the-evidence-for-islam-being-true) and in this I did not get an answer or at least a good one. If I dont think there is evidence for something existing and I am just believing purely based on emotion or upbringing and then I leave Islam and rejoin will I be punished? I even read an answer (I cant find it) about why we need God and the most upvoted an answer simply was based upon our emotions. If I were to leave now because I simply just do not agree with this way of thinking and later someone actually gives me evidence so I join back is there any set punishment for this?
Edit: Im talking about if there is any set punishment and if so elaborate and what it is.

Comment: There's only punishment (in this live) for people leaving Islam and publicly propagating it (in a Muslim country) or acting against Islam and Muslimsb(for example fighting against them). Else you'll receive your punishment (or more exactly you'll expect your judgment) on judgment day.

Comment: @Medi1Saif but if I dont see evidence in something and it seems to me to be purely based off emotions why is there punishment for me. I didnt know it was true and to just be blindly following is wrong.

Comment: Allah's orders are clear about this. There's no further evidence required.

Comment: Yes but like by evidence I mean evidence of Islam being true. If I am unaware then why is there punishment for something I didnt know or understand?

Comment: We are not here to discuss Islam, but to inform about it.

Comment: @Medi1Saif then please can you inform me why there is punishment for something I dont fully comprehend/understand

Comment: That is not on-topic. Allah gave an order Muslim (and this is part of the definition of the term Muslim) follows Allah's orders and don't discuss them. He rather tries to get the wisdom behind them. As Allah doesn't order something bad. It is a matter of faith and belief not necessarily a matter of logic. Else 'Omar would never had said to the black stone something like: I know you are just a stone, if Muhammad () didn't kiss you I wouln' t do so.

Comment: @Medi1Saif But above you just said this is about informing. If this is about wisdom then what is the wisom behind giving me punishment for something I didnt unerstand/know/comprehend.

Comment: The wisdom is that you are a Muslim and although knowing this is the worst sin you do it. You must not understand it, as a Muslim you accept it (first) and try to understand it (later) in order to keep your faith. Your question is off-topic as it attracts opinion-based answers and certainly has no direct answer as defined within the scope of our site, further to get an approach to answer one needs to know more about you and your way of thinking. You'd better consider checking our [help] and ask answerable (partial) questions on order to clear a few points.

Comment: But even though I am a Muslim I am somebody who wants to learn the truth. I couldve done the same for all other religions, accept it then understand it etc. But I didnt I want to learn the truth, if something doesnt seem correct then it is wrong to believe it. It is not my fault that I didnt know something I have clearly even made attempts to understand but to no avail. Is it my fault when trying to learn nobody taught me or is it my fault when asking for evidence I was only told to listen to emotions? Isnt opinion based Im simply asking whether theres punishment for someone who seesno evidenc